# Laravel Eloquent join if column null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables users/invoices in 1:n relation. When someone creats an invoice it saves the user_id. Also it's possible (optional) to set a manager (column: project_management_user_id). If there is no manager set (NULL), I want to get the user, who created the record. So for now I have this query. It gives me all invoices with the manager (but not that ones with manager = null.

```
$query = Invoice::join('users', 'invoices.project_management_user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->select('users.name as name', 'users.color as color',  DB::raw("count(invoices.id) as count"))
                ->get();
```

Is it possible to add some if-clause like "if project_management_user_id is null, take the user_id"? I read about the whereNull() function, but it filters my whole query

Answer (score 0):

Use leftJoin instead of join in the query.

Comment: Ok, this is good advice in general, because I select only the columns of the user table. But how can it help me with my "if project_management_user_id is null, take the user_id" problem?